# TimeOutException while calling to a rest service in mule

Tags: rest, http, request, timeout, mule

I need to call a rest service for every hour. So I have used a poller component in which I make call to the rest service by the use of http.request.
But with every call I get a TimeOutException. Is there any workaround of this problem. Here is the exception stack

```
  <sub-flow name="sf-vessel-operator-update">
        <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.HashMap" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
        <set-session-variable variableName="originalPayload" value="#[payload]" doc:name="Session Variable"/>
        <foreach collection="#[payload.LINEOPERATORCODE]" doc:name="For Each">
            <set-session-variable variableName="LINEOPERATORCODE" value="#[payload]" doc:name="Session Variable"/>
            <flow-ref name="sf-vessel-operator-search" doc:name="sf-vessel-operator-search"/>
            <flow-ref name="sf-process-update-request" doc:name="sf-process-update-request"/>
        </foreach>

    </sub-flow>
    <sub-flow name="sf-vessel-operator-search">

        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="REQUEST RECEIVED TO GET DATA FROM VESSEL_ROUTING WITH THE FOLLOWING DATA : #[payload]"/>
        <set-session-variable variableName="IDCONTRACTOR" value="null" doc:name="Session Variable"/>
        <set-session-variable variableName="IDLINEOPERATOR" value="null" doc:name="Session Variable"/>
        <logger message="IDContractor = #[sessionVars.IDCONTRACTOR]****************IDLINEOPERATOR = #[message.payload.IDLINEOPERATOR]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <enricher target="#[sessionVars.IDCONTRACTOR]" doc:name="me-get-idcontractor">
            <processor-chain doc:name="Processor Chain">
                <set-payload value="select distinct IDMEMBER from member_industry where chtradingcode='#[sessionVars.originalPayload['TERMINALID']]'" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
                <flow-ref name="sf-query-member-industry" doc:name="sf-query-member-industry"/>
            </processor-chain>

        </enricher>
        <enricher doc:name="me-get-lineoperator" target="#[sessionVars.IDLINEOPERATOR]">
            <processor-chain doc:name="Processor Chain">
                <set-payload value="select distinct IDMEMBER from member_industry where chtradingcode='#[sessionVars.LINEOPERATORCODE]'" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
                <flow-ref name="sf-query-member-industry" doc:name="sf-query-member-industry"/>
            </processor-chain>

        </enricher>
        <logger message="IDCONTRACTOR : #[sessionVars.IDCONTRACTOR], IDLINEOPERATOR : #[sessionVars.IDLINEOPERATOR]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <expression-component doc:name="Expression"><![CDATA[String cql3Query = "SELECT * FROM VESSEL_OPERATOR WHERE CHLLOYDSNUMBER =  '"  + sessionVars.originalPayload['LLOYDSNUMBER']  + "'";

if ( sessionVars.IDCONTRACTOR != null   ) {
  cql3Query = cql3Query + "  and IDCONTRACTOR = '"+sessionVars.IDCONTRACTOR + "'" ;
}

if ( sessionVars.IDLINEOPERATOR != null  ) {
  cql3Query = cql3Query + "  and IDLINEOPERATOR  = '"+sessionVars.IDLINEOPERATOR + "'";
}
if ( sessionVars.originalPayload['VOYAGENUMBER']  != null  &&   sessionVars.originalPayload['VOYAGENUMBER'].length() > 0 ) {
     cql3Query = cql3Query + " and CHOUTVOYAGENUMBER  = '"+sessionVars.originalPayload['VOYAGENUMBER'] +"'";
}
payload = cql3Query ;
]]></expression-component>
        <flow-ref name="sf-select-query-database" doc:name="sf-select-query-database"/>       
    </sub-flow>
    <sub-flow name="sf-process-update-request">
        <set-variable variableName="status" value="#[message.outboundProperties['http.status']]" doc:name="Variable"/>
        <logger message="Status : #[flowVars.status]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <choice doc:name="Choice">
            <when expression="#[flowVars.status == '200']">
                <expression-component doc:name="Expression"><![CDATA[String cql3Query = " UPDATE  VESSEL_OPERATOR  SET " ;

if ( sessionVars.LINEOPERATORCODE != null  ) {
  cql3Query = cql3Query + " CHLINEOPERATORCODE  = '"+ sessionVars.LINEOPERATORCODE + "'";
}

if ( sessionVars.originalPayload['LINEOPERATORNAME'] != null  ) {
  cql3Query = cql3Query + "', CHLINEOPERATORNAME= '"+sessionVars.originalPayload['LINEOPERATORNAME'] + "'";
}



cql3Query = cql3Query + "   WHERE IDCONTRACTOR = '" + sessionVars.IDCONTRACTOR  + "'" +
                                              "  AND CHLLOYDSNUMBER = '" +sessionVars.originalPayload['LLOYDSNUMBER']  + "'" +
                                              "  AND CHOUTVOYAGENUMBER = '" +sessionVars.originalPayload['VOYAGENUMBER']  + "'" +
                                              "  AND IDLINEOPERATOR = '" + sessionVars.IDLINEOPERATOR  + "'"  ;



payload = cql3Query;
]]></expression-component>
                <flow-ref name="sf-update-query-database" doc:name="sf-update-query-database"/>
            </when>
            <when expression="#[flowVars.status == '204']">
                <expression-component doc:name="Expression"><![CDATA[



flowVars.LINEOPERATORNAME = "null";
if (sessionVars.originalPayload['LINEOPERATORNAME'] != null  ) {
  flowVars.LINEOPERATORNAME =sessionVars.originalPayload['LINEOPERATORNAME'];
}

 String cql = 
                         " INSERT INTO VESSEL_OPERATOR ( IDCONTRACTOR, CHLLOYDSNUMBER, CHOUTVOYAGENUMBER, IDLINEOPERATOR,CHLINEOPERATORCODE," + 
                         "CHLINEOPERATORNAME )" +  " VALUES (  " +                          
                        "'"  + sessionVars.IDCONTRACTOR + "'," +
                        "'" + sessionVars.originalPayload['LLOYDSNUMBER'] +"',"+
                        "'" +sessionVars.originalPayload['VOYAGENUMBER']+"',"+
                        "'" +   sessionVars.IDLINEOPERATOR +"',"+
                        "'" + sessionVars.LINEOPERATORCODE +"',"+                        
                        "'"  +  flowVars.LINEOPERATORNAME +"')";

payload = cql;]]></expression-component>
                <flow-ref name="sf-insert-query-database" doc:name="sf-insert-query-database"/>
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <logger message="Sorry Default executed" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
    </sub-flow>   
</mule>
```

Comment: Are you able to call that service outside mule without timing out?

Comment: @Charu Khurana: I think the problem is, the back end execution of rest api is fine, but it gives kind of warning : "Payload is a Map which will be used to generate an url encoded http body but Contenty-Type specified is application/json;charset=windows-1252 and not application/x-www-form-urlencoded" . This is causing timeout exception at client side

Comment: Show your config where you're calling service and how `Content-Type` is set

Comment: @Charu Khurana:  I do not see I am setting the content type, I have just pasted my xml. Could you please tell why I am getting the above error while testing from postman

Comment: @Charu Khurana:  I think the culprit is for each